# mongodb: array contains and array don't contains

Tags: mongodb

How do I check if list1 contains A and list2 don't contains A?
both list1 and list2 are array (list2 can be empty or not set)

I tried query:

```
{
  'list1':'A', 
  'list2':{ '$ne':'A'}
}
```

but I'm getting results with list1 contains A and list2 contains A.
if I remove `'list2':{ '$ne':'A'} ...`results is the same, likes list2 part don't metter

strange ...am I doing something wrong?

Comment: can you show your documents structure and data?

Comment: damn, its working now, i don't know what i was doing ..im really sorry .. 

right syntax is : 

{ 'list1':'A', 'list2':{ $ne:'A'} }

Comment: actually no ..try this example

insert this two records
{
        'a1': [ 'A' ],
        'a2': [ 'A' ]

}

{
        'a1': [ 'A' ]

}

query1 (2 results)
{
        'a1': 'A'

}

query2 (1 result)
{
        'a1': 'A',
        'a2': { $ne:'A'}

}

..now update the second record
{
        '$set': {
                "a2.0": 'A'
        }

}

..and try query2 ..same results!?
if I update 2 second record with full set query2 works ..strange
find show the same data

Comment: @AndrewOrsich 
# data
db.test.insert({'a1': [ 'A' ],'a2': [ 'A' ]});
db.test.insert({'a1': [ 'A' ]});

# query1 (2 results)
db.test.find({'a1': 'A'});

# query2 (1 result)
db.test.find({'a1': 'A','a2': { $ne:'A'}} );

# update the second record (replaxe X mongoid)
db.test.update({ _id: X }, {'$set': {"a2.0": 'A'}});

# query2 ...1 result ..should be none
db.test.find({'a1': 'A','a2': { $ne:'A'}} );

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was updating it wrong. Should be this:

```
db.test.update({ _id: X }, {'$push': {"a2": 'A'}});
```

Or this:

```
db.test.update({ _id: X }, {'$set': {"a2": ['A']}});
```

the document looks like this:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4dbacb40696b6ede04c5ef97"), "a1" : [ "A" ], "a2" :
{ "0" : "A" } }
```

Where it's correct that `{"0": "A"}` is not equal to `A`